# Play Framework, RAW field doesn't work properly

Tags: oracle, playframework, playframework-1.x

I´ve got a User model like this one

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SHOPPER")
public class User extends GenericModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="SHRFNBR")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="SEQ_SHP", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_SHP", sequenceName="SEQ_SHP", allocationSize=1)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="SHLOGID")
    public String email;

    @Column(name="SHLPSWD")
    public String password;


    public static User isUser(String user, String pass){
        return User.find("byEmailAndPassword", user, pass).first();
    }
}
```

On DB password its RAW type and on Controller it´s encoded with RSA.

The main thing it´s that it doesn't find any result because the binary that goes into the DB seems different than the one that's on the field.

At first I thought it could be some character encoding issue on the Application but then I pointed to the same DB but on production and it worked. So I checked the Devel DB and found another Characterset instead of **ISO-8859-1** (prod) was **ISO-8859-15** (devel) that seems little different.

After updating the devel characterset the situation it´s the same. Is there any other place where the RSA string is getting wrong encoded on DB?

**Process description:**

The process is a login process where the user inserts email and password, the last one gets encoded with RSA and the result it´s sent to DB for comparison.
The field on DB contains a value like this one:

CB4F3ECB7763C98EF67CA761700D1FB255F90E4473B1BB594B2238756307DF2D155D57A2CBA2930C‌162CB0634765D48EA111F743F6825F2457340148F680E300

**More info:**

- DB Oracle 10g
- Play Framework 1.2.4

Comment: to help you we need more info about the process : in a normal process your password is encoded into the db and when you check it, you encod in the same way the password in the controller and use your finder to check if passwords match

Comment: @SebCesbron the password remains stored on DB at this moment, this process is a login process. When the user inserts email and password the last one gets encoded and it´s send to the DB for comparison. On DB the field contains this (ex: CB4F3ECB7763C98EF67CA761700D1FB255F90E4473B1BB594B2238756307DF2D155D57A2CBA2930C162CB0634765D48EA111F743F6825F2457340148F680E300)

Comment: Are the contents of `pass` parameter cleartext or encrypted? Where does the encrypting take place? Can you share that part of code as well?

Comment: @Tom they´re encoded before it goes into bbdd. It gets encoded on the Controller with RSA-like util. After all I´ve solved it on a dirty way editing the hash before it goes on bbdd and now it works properly but still trying to find a better way to do this and a real fix to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't map binary data to a String, use byte[] instead, this way you won't have any character encoding issues.